# API Яндекс.Метрика, не выдаёт счётчик для часа/даты/месяца/года, если посещений не было

Tags: yandex-metrika-api

Делаю запрос к API вида `https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data?dimensions=ym:s:hour&metrics=ym:s:visits,ym:s:users,ym:s:newUsers,ym:s:newUserVisitsPercentage,ym:s:bounceRate&date1=<from>&date2=<to>&ids=<id>&oauth_token=<token>&sort=ym:s:hour`
В час и два часа ночи не было посещений и Яндекс API не возвращает эти поля вообще, но они необходимы. В случае с часами добавить недостающие проблемы не составляет, а что если пустой месяц или год? За всем не уследишь. Пытался найти параметр который заставит отдавать даже нулевые данные, но так и не смог найти.

Comment: проверяйте на наличие этих данных, если их нет, генерите свои пустые, если они так уж важны

Comment: Для часов я так и делаю, но есть ещё дни, недели, месяца, года и указан может быть любой диапазон. За всем не уследишь, да и смысл? Мне почему то кажется, что есть возможность получить пустые, но в этих доках ничего не найти. Даже внутренний поиск часто ведёт на битые ссылки. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, получил ответ от Яндекс.Метрика. Ответ - никак. :) Прямым текстом намекают "мучайтесь сами". Сервис богов. 
P.S. API совместимый с GA тоже не работает, даже на их example'ах. Может и есть костыли, но мне хватило, Карл. :)